# How can I convert my comments to Log.Information call on compile time?

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I want to log my comments on source file in final assembly. I am building help file system based on comments so I can't convert it to Log.Information calls.

I just want my final executable has `Log.Information("//Comment on source")` calls and my source still has `//Comment on source`. How can I do that?

Comment: Log.Information("@//Comment on source")

Comment: I don't believe you can do what you are asking. Reflection doesn't work for comments (and I believe comments are removed in release builds). All-in-all, it seems like a very bad way to document a program, comments are for programmers, not users.

Comment: Thank you guys. Although I don't know if anything is possible with comments, I think that there are some code injectors to achieve something like that.